# Haskell socket receive timeout

Tags: sockets, haskell, timeout

I'm writing SNTP client for windows in haskell. Here is the snippet that throws `Exception: mallocPlainForeignPtrBytes: size must be >= 0`, namely `recv` function does:

```
getResponse :: HostName -> IO (Maybe String)
getResponse server = withSocketsDo $ do
    s <- socket AF_INET Datagram defaultProtocol
    setRecvTimeout s waitingTime
    host <- getHostByName server
    let hostAddress = head $ hostAddresses $ host
    connect s (SockAddrInet sntpPort hostAddress)
    sendAll s requestPacket
    response <- timeout (-1) (recv s 1024)
    return $ BC.unpack <$> response
```

The main problem is that `timeout` does not really prevent sockets from blocking. Also `setSocketOption` didn't work for me and `setRecvTimeout` works, but `recv` throws an exception when connected to invalid server. So how do I timeout `recv` properly?

I do not want to handle this exception with try-catch since it's not really a functional way, and I'm sure there must be much more simple and elegant way to do it.

Comment: I would wrap the `setRecvTimeout` solution to obtain a more "functional" primitive. Please note that `timeout` does not guarantee atomicity: the timeout might trigger after the `recv` has received the data but before it is actually returned. In that case, your `timeout` may return `Nothing` and the message is lo longer in the OS socket queue.

Comment: In what way would you wrap it, to be concrete? My `timeout` here does nothing, just wraps result in `Just`. I tried using it with the actual timing, not `-1`, but it was just stuck when there was no reply from the server. Atomicity is not necessary since if server is responsive, result usually bounces immediately.